# Generating high current at low voltage from DC voltage supply

Tags: dc-dc-converter, inductor

**Main Question:**

What role do inductors play in allowing an 8 volt, 2amp max power supply, to power a 2.7volt 6.5amp resistive load?

**Details:**

Out of boredom / convenience I converted an old e-cigarette to run off a variable DC power supply.

It used to run on two 18650 cells.

I am running it at 8 volts, with a voltage divider (two 10k ohms resistors) to trick the battery management that there is a battery (it taps between the two cells, so it expects half the total voltage.)

I realised that a DC power supply rated at 2amp max was likely to not work, but I though I would try anyway.

This is because even at lower wattage of 17 watts, on 0.42 ohm of Kanthal wire, the ecig would power it at 2.7 volts, which would be 6.5 amperes, which is quite a bit even for an 18650.

To my surprise, nothing popped / let out magic smoke / cut out, it runs totally fine. I can run it for the full 10 seconds it will allow me to.

Below is a picture of the underside of an ecig main board. This isn't the same as mine, but similar. I think they are basically switching power supplies, with constant current output (the voltage will slightly fluctuate with the heat of the coil.)

[image: Picture of an ecig power supply]

Being a hobbyist, inductors are not something I've used yet, so they are a little magic to me, but I'm guessing they play a vital role in allowing this high current to be supplied at at a lower voltage.

Edit: It only seems to draw 1 ampere from the power supply. (Checked with a multimeter.)

Comment: This is impossible: input power is 8 × 2 = 16W and output power is 2.7 × 6.5 = 17.55W.

Comment: it only pulls 1 amp from the 8v supply after checking with a multimeter. So technically, 8watt in 17.55w out.  So could it not be charging up the inductor, (as per below answer), then releasing it? Then after stops pulling current, it recharges the inductor?

Comment: This is only possible if your e-cigarette does not **constantly** draw 6.5 amps (which is reasonable), in which case you can use power from capacitors and charge them when the cigarette is drawing a lower current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An inductor is a short-term energy storage, with the stored energy being proportional (or in the presence of saturation, related) to the current.  So you can "charge" an inductor on a large voltage until it reaches the desired current, then "discharge" it at a lower voltage.  In order to have uninterrupted current flow, you'd use capacitors on both sides to buffer the voltage between engagements of the inductor.

Since energy preservation is a thing, the duty cycle of the inductor will be inversely proportional to the respective voltage it is charged/discharged with.  If the switching frequencies are high, there is comparatively little energy that is actually stored and retrieved in each cycle, but the energy flow can still be significant.